# Postgresql Copy from text file with a newline character column

Tags: postgresql

I m trying to import a txt file into a postgresql table. However, in the txt data, there is a value including newline.
When exporting txt file, I can change row seperator different than "\n" but i couldnt find any parameter to change row seperator for copy command.
OS: linux

Is there a row seperator parameter for copy command in postgresql?

Example:
Txt file:( delimiter "|")

1st line:

```
ab|dc|blabla|ef
```

2nd line:

```
ab|dc|bla
bla|ef
```

In the second row , third column include bla (newline) bla.

Postgres command:

```sql
copy tablename from 'a.txt' with delimiter '|' null '';
```

Comment: Read  the section on 'File Formats` here [Copy](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html).  From there you will find out you need to use the `csv` format instead of the `text` format you are using now.

Comment: Now, i m trying the csv format. But there is no record seperator option. Just a workaround by quote option. in the csv or txt ouput, there is no quotes for columns.

Comment: Yes there is. It accepts the same options as `text`, the defaults are just different. Read the 'File Formats' section in the link I posted.

Comment: I just mean there is no row seperator option. (There is a delimiter options for fields). Postgresql expects  "\n" for linux "\r\n" for windows. Could you give an example for that? I ve read the section you referred but I couldnt find the row seperator option part. Unfortunately,  the csv file is from different source and  in my csv file there is no quotes for strings.

Comment: From the docs, you don't need a  row separator option: "The values in each record are separated by the DELIMITER character. If the value contains the delimiter character, the QUOTE character, the NULL string, a carriage return, or line feed character, then the whole value is prefixed and suffixed by the QUOTE character, and any occurrence within the value of a QUOTE character or the ESCAPE character is preceded by the escape character. "

Comment: It expects quote character prefix and suffix for the value including newline character. However, in my csv file, there is no quote prefix and suffix. There is an example at first post for the value including newline character. Postgresql assumes this newline as a new row and raise an error.

Comment: I missed the second line example. That won't work unless the value is quoted. You can't force the export program to quote all values? What is the export program?

Comment: Using odisqlunload method of oracle data integrator. (Odi12c).  With jyhton code, i can add prefix and suffix for characters but it is complicated and take time.

Comment: Yeah, I don't see any provision to quote values in `odisqlunload`.

Comment: thank you for your time